# private method `active_for_authentication?' called for #<User:0x00007f2d0e04d3e0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

After signup i have this error:

> `NoMethodError` in `RegistrationsController#create`
>   private method `'active_for_authentication?'` called for `<User:0x00007f2d0e04d3e0>`

```
**Extracted source (around line #430):**

428 def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
429 if respond_to_without_attributes?(method, true)
430    super
431 else
432  match = match_attribute_method?(method.to_s)
434  match ? attribute_missing(match, *args, &block) : super
```

in my user model i have:

```
def active_for_authentication? 
 super && approved? 
end 

def inactive_message 
 approved? ? super : :not_approved
end
```

Comment: active_for_authentication?  should be public, did you put it in private ?

Comment: oufff thanks, it wasn't public.
have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined it into the private methods section. Make it public.